# How to put a square container inside ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to put a square container inside `ListTile` in Flutter?

`leading` has a square container which appears as a rectangle in the list as shown in the screenshot.

Is there a better alternative than `ListTile` or am I doing something wrong? Will `SingleChildScrollView` be more useful here?

```
  Widget dynamicListTileWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              "Label space",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                          height: 2,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                          title: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Title",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )),
                          leading: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                              child: Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 100,
                                  color: Colors.green)),
                          subtitle: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
                              child: Text("Subtitle")));
                    }))
          ],
        )));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its because

*'Leading widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, '
'or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget '
'(see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4)',*

And it will make sure container is a big as it can be. You can try enforcing a constraint using AspectRatio or SizedBox, Another way would be using custom **Row**. For Example:

```
AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: 1,
   child: Container(
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   color: Colors.green)),
```